# Jquery Ajax doesn't pass data to action method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

Here is my AJAX method:

```
function SendMessage(contactId, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $("#text").val();

        const dataObject = {
            contactId: contactId,
            content: content
        }

        console.log(dataObject)

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/Contact/Reply",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataObject,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
                if (res != null) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Sent successfully!',
                        '',
                        'success'
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Data comes from :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reply to sender"
            name="Content" required="" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"
           onclick="SendMessage(@item.Id,event)" />
</form>
```

But AJAX doesn't pass data to action method:

[image]

I am sure data is there, as it appears in console :

[image]

How can I send data to action method, any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try the following, change the line `data: dataObject` to `data: JSON.stringify( dataObject )`, then see if it works.

Comment: @BolaAdelNassif I did,but still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use default content format?

Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to use the default value. The default is: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

If will not work try to clean a browser cache.

Comment: after changed `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to  `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",` it worked, thanks for your answer